A fantasy book about a boy with a pet wolf or dog that's on the run
I'm looking to identify this fantasy book about a boy with a pet wolf or dog that's on the run. This is actually for my brother, and this is what he told me.
It's a Percy Jackson-like book where it's set in the real world with a fantasy aspect in it. He said it was about a guy with a wolf or dog companion who he thinks was on the run from, like, his father or something.
Some of the info might be off because he's almost 20 and it's a book he read in elementary school. He also said he remembers it had a red cover, but that might be his memory playing a trick on him.
Any books with any description close to this would be really helpful.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when your brother read the book and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Why is the dog on the run? Is he a bad boy?

Is the boy actually young, or just young-looking?  Does he have superhuman/demigodlike or magical powers?  Does he use a particular weapon?  What breed of dog?

There's Dawn Wind by Rosemary Sutcliffe. Set in Britain at the time of the Saxon invasion. Features a Celtic boy who is wounded on the losing side of a battle and ends up with one of the King's war dogs, who becomes his companion through much of the book. Boy gets enslaved and freed by the Saxons. No fantasy component, other than being construction of the Saxon invasion from the perspective of a native.

It's not quite what I would call Percy Jackson-like, but in a lot of ways this sounds like The Talisman by Stephen King and Peter Straub. It's possible he could've read it in elementary school, I don't think I was more than a year or two older than that when I first read it.

The main character, a boy named Jack, has the ability the "flip" between the real world and a parallel fantasy version of the world. He spends most of the time in the real world, but in places where elements of the fantasy world are bleeding through.

Jack is on the run from his evil "uncle" in both versions of the world. He's crossing the United States/"The Territories" to find a magical artifact.

His companion is a "Wolf" that he calls "Wolf", but he's not a literal wolf. He's a wolf-person from the fantasy world, and much is made of his simple, loyal and loving doglike nature. He very much dislikes the sounds and smells of our world. I could see a younger reader misremembering him years later as an actual wolf.

Some editions of the book had a red cover, and others had lots of red text on a black cover.


